# UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR for custom UIVIew

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to apply `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` for my custom class

**MyCustomView.h**

```
@interface MyCustomView : UIView
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage *indicatorImage UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *myColor UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;

- (void) doSomething;
@end
```

**MyCustomView.m**

```
@interface MyCustomView()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *indicatorImageView;
@end

@implementation MyCustomView

-(void)initialize {
   [self addSubview:self.indicatorImageView];
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
    if(self) {
        [self initialize];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void) doSomething {
    // here indicatorImage and myColor are nil!    
}

- (void) setIndicatorImage:(UIImage *)indicatorImage {
    _indicatorImage = indicatorImage;
    self.indicatorImageView.image = indicatorImage;
    [self.indicatorImageView setNeedsLayout];
}

- (UIImageView *)indicatorImageView
{
    if (!_indicatorImageView) {
        _indicatorImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
        _indicatorImageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    }
    return _indicatorImageView;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // here indicatorImage and myColor are NOT nil!
}
@end
```

I set my appearance in AppDelegate. I added my view to storyboard and assigned `MyCustomView` class. In `viewDidLoad` I call `doSomething` method from code above and surprisingly both variable are nil. Another strange thing is `indicatorImageView` contains image I've set in AppDelegate. And finally, I both variables are set to right values in `drawRect`.

The question is: what I'm doing wrong? How can I get right values in `doSomething` method?

Comment: when do you call the doSomething method?

Comment: @LombaX I call it in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the appearance is set after the viewDidLoad method.
When the viewDidLoad method on the View Controller is called, the view has ben loaded, but it has not been added yet to the view hierarchy.

If you put a breakpoint in the `setMyColor:` method and print the backtrace, you will see that:

- the `setMyColor:` method is called after `viewDidLoad` on the controller
- the appearance is applied after the `addSubview` method, which happens always after the `viewDidLoad` method on the parent controller.

Look at frame 8, `_applyAppearanceInvocations`

```
frame #1: 0x00d8d18d CoreFoundation`__invoking___ + 29
frame #2: 0x00eadb92 CoreFoundation`-[NSInvocation invokeUsingIMP:] + 242
frame #3: 0x0186364b UIKit`__workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget_block_invoke + 95
frame #4: 0x012be830 UIKit`+[UIView _performCustomizableAppearanceModifications:] + 29
frame #5: 0x018635e1 UIKit`workaround10030904InvokeWithTarget + 1047
frame #6: 0x0185d2f8 UIKit`+[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:matchingSelector:] + 4107
frame #7: 0x0185db14 UIKit`+[_UIAppearance _applyInvocationsTo:window:] + 56
frame #8: 0x012d7b1b UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _applyAppearanceInvocations] + 287
frame #9: 0x012d85a4 UIKit`__88-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:]_block_invoke + 65
frame #10: 0x012d8531 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _performUpdatesForPossibleChangesOfIdiom:orScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 204
frame #11: 0x012d845f UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didChangeFromIdiom:onScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 53
frame #12: 0x012d8422 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didChangeFromIdiomOnScreen:traverseHierarchy:] + 172
frame #13: 0x012d79cd UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 1722
frame #14: 0x012d7666 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 851
frame #15: 0x012cea57 UIKit`__45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 154
frame #16: 0x012ce9b5 UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 458
frame #17: 0x012da428 UIKit`-[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1943
frame #18: 0x012ccdbd UIKit`-[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
```

Comment: Thank you! That's clear, I've also watched WWDC 2011 video on that theme. But are there any way to call `doSomething` when controller loads?

Comment: call it in the `viewDidAppear:` method or, better, in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks like UIView appearance is set when view is added to hierarchy.